# Custom Shortcuts in WinEdt 8.0

Tags: winedt

How do I add a panel with all the math, greek, international symbols and other environments in WinEdt 8.0. I couldn't find any customizations for this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a tool bar button in winedt 8.x as in this picture:

[image]

Press it to open the symbol panel shown below. There are different tabs using which you can insert different symbols.